# React image loading

Tags: reactjs

I need to dynamically load the images from a folder.

I did store my images in src/client/img, and I wrote a simple component to load the png files:

```
class ImageStore {

  constructor() {
    var r = require.context('../img', true, /\.(png)$/)

    this.images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { this.images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
  }

  names() {
    return Object.keys(this.images);
  }

  image(name) {
    var img = this.images[name];

    if( !img ) {
      throw `Image not found: ${name}`;
    }

    return img;
  }
}

export const imageStore = new ImageStore();
```

In my home page, it works fine:

```
class HomeView extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Images</h2>
            <table><tbody>
              {
                imageStore.names().map( (imageName) => (
                    <tr key={imageName}><td>{imageName}</td><td><img src={imageStore.image(imageName)}/></td></tr>
                ))
              }
              </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default HomeView;
```

So I get:
[image]

And the browser send the following request to the server to load the images:
Request URL:http://localhost:3100/08f1a78cea5a9873b84bb8936664277b.png

Which is OK.

But...
When I include the same code in a page displayed by a route such as http://localhost:3000/space/10002, images are not found because the browser add the "/space" url prefix.

Here is the request:
Request URL:http://localhost:3100/space/d7f44567c7944ac4cc4cd00e3e140282.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Here is the value returned by imageSTore.names():
Array(55)
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-128.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-16.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-24.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-32.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-48.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-64.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-128.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-16.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-24.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-32.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-48.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-64.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-128.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-16.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-24.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-32.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-48.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-64.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-128.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-16.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-24.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-32.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-48.png"
"IndoorEnvironmentObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-64.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-128.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-16.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-24.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-32.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-48.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-alert-64.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-128.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-16.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-24.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-32.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-48.png"
"WeatherObserved/humidity/humidity-normal-64.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-128.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-16.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-24.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-32.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-48.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-alert-64.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-128.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-16.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-24.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-32.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-48.png"
"WeatherObserved/temperature/temperature-normal-64.png"
"localized/localized-no-24.png"
"localized/localized-no-32.png"
"localized/localized-no-48.png"
"localized/localized-yes-24.png"
"localized/localized-yes-32.png"
"localized/localized-yes-48.png"
"notFound.png"

I cannot figure how to fix that.
Any idea?

Thanks.
Thibault.

Comment: Could you please log `console.log(ImageStore.names())`..It'll help debug the issue

Comment: Hi,I just add the imageStore.names in my post.  tks for your time.

Comment: My mistake...I confused image names with the formatted urls..please run `ImageStore.names().forEach(item => console.log(ImageStore.image(item)))`. Basically I want to know whether the formatted urls you're getting are relative urls or absolute urls.

Comment: I found the problem. In my webpackconfig, publicPath: '/' was missing in the output conf. In this case, it looks that react use the request URL to fetch the images. Weired no?

Comment: Here what image(item) give when publicPath set to /: /e5814bd24fa5ed6f849af51b5daa589a.png. Without the publicPath config, it give: e5814bd24fa5ed6f849af51b5daa589a.png. So, the image src is interpreted as a relative url, that's why the request is sent to /space/e5814bd24fa5ed6f849af51b5daa589a.png and return a 404.  Thanks for your help.